# Real and virtual photons in the standard model

Tags: standard-model

In the Standard Model, the mass of the photon is zero, while the photon becomes massive if it acts as a mediator between two electrons. Why does this happen? Does it mean that the Standard Model cannot describe the interaction between two electrons?

Comment: *"while the photon becomes massive if it acts as a mediator between two electrons"* [citation needed]

Comment: Virtual photons don't have mass. They are off shell.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm not sure what your question is.   A photon has no rest mass, but it has energy mass, so there's no tangible difference between a photon that acts as a force between charged particles and a photon in what we call light or EM radiation.  As far as I know, the standard model describes the interactions between electrons quite well.

Comment: The answers by Fredric Brunner and @ACuriousMind to [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/122408/why-arent-all-photons-virtual-particles-even-in-the-vacuum-of-empty-space/122410#122410) might be helpful in clearing a few things up for you. :)

Answer (score -2):

The relativistic mass of the photon is not zero, it is $\frac{h\nu}{c^2}$.

The rest mass of the photon is zero, but according to spec. rel it goes always with $c$.

Comment: The concept of relativistic mass that you are apparently using when you say "the mass of the photon is not zero" is considered [obsolete by most](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/133395/50583). No quantum field theorist (and this question is about the Standard Model, a QFT) would agree to the statement that "the mass of the photon is not zero".

Comment: @ACuriousMind I read this, moment